# Appropriate time to do amavasya tharpanam in the below instance

Tags: astrology, calendar, panchang

There are certain instances that amavasya starts from 7 am and ends the next day by 6/15 am. In this case on which day to do the amavasya tharpanam? The previous day it starts from 7  am that is one hour [assume the sun rise at 6 am] after sunrise. The next day it ends by 6/15 am where the thithi is there during sunrise. Normally tharpanam to be performed by 11 am but now due to office workings it is done by 8 am. In the above case on which day the tharpanam for pithrus to be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decision about 'tithi' (e.g. pornima, pratipada, etc.)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/decision-about-tithi-e-g-pornima-pratipada-etc)