# Why have we celebrated Dussehra today instead of tomorrow?

Tags: festivals, panchang, navrathri

Whatever I know for consideration of Tithi from Panchangam is whichever Tithi falls on the sunrise, that is considered for whole the day.

For example, yesterday there was Ashtami on sunrise and Ashtami Tithi holded upto 12:50 pm, after then Navami is started. Since there was Ashtami on sunrise, Ashtami is considered for whole the day and hence there was Durgashtami on 17 Oct. 2018.

Now, talking about for today (18 Oct. 2018) there was Navami on sunrise and holding up to 3:30 pm and after then Dashami occurs. So, there should Navami be considered for whole the day.  However, as we know we have celebrated Dussehara today.

Ideally, if you observe Tithi timings for tomorrow there is Dashami on sunrise and holding up to evening (6 pm). So, there should be Dashami considered for whole 19 Oct. 2018 and hence Dussehra should be celebrated tomorrow.

Then why have we celebrated Dussehra today? Isn't Dussehra the 10th day of Navaratri i.e **Vijaya Dashami**? So, I am bit confused regarding counting Tithi for today. I am sure there is something I'm missing. Is there anything regarding Nakshatra or other things considered for counting tithi? or what am I missing? Looking for an answer explaining justification.

Comment: I think this could be because Dashami tithi started today. Even though, we (from Andhra) celebrated today, [Drik Panchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/day-panchang.html?date=19/10/2018) says tomorrow is Dashara (Vijaya Dashami).

Comment: This is based on Tithi Nirnaya. Yesterday Sandhi Puja of Durga Puja was done at around noon but yesterday was Mahashtami only and Sandhi Puja is done at the junction of Ashtami and Navami (we have 48 mins to complete it). That means Navami had already started yesterday only around noon. So, today Dasami also has already started around noon. That's why..

Comment: There seems one day difference sometimes in different geographical locations and sects...I hv seen it in last 4 years for different festivals including Deepawali, Janmashtami, Vijaya Dashmi.. *there r two things associated with most of the festivals: nakshatra & tithi; best time to celebrate is when both occurs at the same time but if not then few sects celebrate occurring to tithi and few according to nakshatra which might result in 1 day difference* ...bdw we will celebrate Dushera tomorrow :)....

Comment: your comments above are worthy to be posted as answers with a little bit addition. Nice ones. Pl. consider posting as answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decision about 'tithi' (e.g. pornima, pratipada, etc.)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/decision-about-tithi-e-g-pornima-pratipada-etc)

Comment: In Punjab we celebrated  Dusshera yesterday on 19th October  2018.I even don't know why other states like Maharashtra  celebrated Dusshera on 18th October 2018.@Pandya

Answer (score 3):

There are generally below factors to celebrate any Hindu festival:

- Calendar category (Lunar, Solar)
- Calendar subcategory (Purnimanta, Amanta)
- Hindu month (e.g. Ashwin, Bhadrapada etc.)
- Paksha (e.g. Shukla, Krishna)
- Tithi (e.g. Dashami, Ashtami etc.)
- Nakshatra (e.g. Shravana, Rohini etc.)
- Kaal (e.g. Vijaya, Nishita etc.)

As per Lunar Purnimanta calendar, Dussehra or Vijayadashami is observed on **Shukla** Paksha **Dashami** during **Ashwin** month. Other factors to be considered are **Shravana** Nakshatra and **Vijaya** Kaal.

This year,

> Dashami Tithi Begins = 15:28 on 18/Oct/2018
>
> Dashami Tithi Ends = 17:57 on 19/Oct/2018
>
> Shravana Nakshatra Begins = 21:29 on 17/Oct/2018
>
> Shravana Nakshatra Ends = 00:34 on 19/Oct/2018

When such conflicts arise, the different sects/locations give preference to one day over another so this year (2018) few locations celebrated on 18th and few location on 19th October.

---

This conflict may arise in many festivals, the recent example is Janmashtami 2018 in which the day is decided by **Ashtami Tithi**, **Rohini Nakshatra** and **Nishita Kaal**. Few people gave preference to Nishita Kaal and few Rohini Nakshatra which resulted in one day difference.

---

**References**

- [drikpanchang: 2018 Bengal Vijayadashami](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/vijayadashami/bengal/vijayadashami-date-time.html)
- [navbharattimes: Dussehra on 18th or 19th Oct](https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/astro/rashifal/planet-prediction/2018-vijayadashami-tithi-muhurta-pujan-49476/)
- [navbharattimes: Dussehra festival](https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/astro/dharam-karam/vrat-tyohar/2018-vijyadashmi-puja-muhurta-time-panchang-49485/)
- [bhaskar: 2018 Vijayadashami shubh-muhurat as per tithi nakshatra](https://www.bhaskar.com/religion/dharam/dussehra-2018-vijayadashami-shubh-muhurat-as-per-tithi-nakshatra-and-hindu-panchang-5970430.html)
- [drikpanchang: 2018 Krishna Janmashtami](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/lord-krishna/krishna-janmashtami-date-time.html?year=2018)
- [drikpanchang: Mysore Dasara Calendar](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dasara/mysore/mysore-dasara-calendar.html)
- [drikpanchang: 2018 Vijayadashami](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/vijayadashami/vijayadashami-date-time.html)
- [drikpanchang: 2018 Ashtami Rohini](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/lord-krishna/solar-kerala-janmashtami-date-time.html?year=2018)

Comment: Nice, so which Nakshatra is considered for Dussehra Muhurta?

Comment: Thanks. Btw, do Shravana Nakshatra comes around Vijaya Dashami every year? oh! yes, I just checked Panchangam, yes it does :)

Comment: Small correction: According to Tithi consideration only Dussehra was on 19th and according to Tithi + Nakshara consideration, Dussehra was on 18th. (I think you said reverse)

Comment: There is no combination of Dashami and Shravana on 19th. (see the timings of Nakshatra)

Comment: However that combination was for half day on 18th. Ok let me check reference you have given :)

Comment: Btw, [this article](https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/astro/dharam-karam/vrat-tyohar/2018-vijyadashmi-puja-muhurta-time-panchang-49485/) cited on wikipedia looks useful.