# Why is Janmashtami celebrated on 2 dates in some parts of India?

Tags: krishna, festivals, panchang

For example, in Gurgaon in India, a few people are saying that Janmashtami will be celebrated on 23rd. Google shows 24th.

Also, I guess this time *Rohini Nakshatra* and *Ashtami* is more close to 24th. So why would it be celebrated on 23rd?

So why is it like that?

Comment: the day is decided by Ashtami Tithi, Rohini Nakshatra and Nishita Kaal. Few people give preference to Nishita Kaal and few Rohini Nakshatra which sometimes results in one day difference..see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29560/12304 (for Vijya Dashmi) but mention Janmashtami example too...

Comment: i believe janmastami and krishna jayanthi are 2 different thing. This time its ashtami and rohini happens on early morning 24 according to drikpancanga.. some people fast on 23 do argya pooja on 24 4:15 when rohini and astami is there and finish fast on 24 8:15 AM when astami ends..uttradhi mutt does fasting on both days 23 and 24th  parana on 25th only..i prefer 24 as morning thithi is the thithi for whole day even it ends and rohini is there in night also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rules for **Krishna Ashtami nirnaya** are quite complex which are explained in [Dharma Bindu: page 8-9](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf) (pdf might get downloaded by clicking on this link), [DHARMA SINDHU: Prathama Parichheda](https://archive.org/details/DHARMASINDHU/page/n39) and [Nirnaya Sindhu: Dwitya Parichheda](https://archive.org/details/NirnayaSindhuHindi/page/n225) etc in detail.

The basic summary of the rules is,

The most auspicious day to celebrate Krishna Janmashtami is when **Bhadrapada
Krishna Paksha (in Purnimanta calendar) Ashtami Tithi** and **Rohini Nakshatra** occurs during **Nishita Kaala** (Hindu midnight). If this auspicious combination happens then, all celebrate the Krishna Janmashtami on the same day.

If this combination doesn't happen like this year:

> Ashtami Tithi Begins - 08:09 AM on Aug 23, 2019
>
> Ashtami Tithi Ends - 08:32 AM on Aug 24, 2019
>
> Rohini Nakshatra Begins - 03:48 AM on Aug 24, 2019
>
> Rohini Nakshatra Ends - 04:17 AM on Aug 25, 2019
>
> ~ [drikpanchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/lord-krishna/krishna-janmashtami-date-time.html)

Then, few would celebrate by giving more preference to Ashtami Tithi and few would celebrate by giving more preference to Rohini Nakshatra.

As mentioned in [this article](https://khabar.ndtv.com/news/faith/janmashtami-2019-date-time-importance-significance-krishna-janmashtami-shubh-muhurat-puja-vidhi-shri-2087048):

> तिथि के हिसाब से जन्‍माष्‍टमी 23 अगस्‍त को मनाई जाएगी. वहीं, रोहिणी नक्षत्र को प्रधानता देने वाले लोग 24 अगस्‍त को जन्‍माष्‍टमी मना सकते हैं
>
> Who give preference to Ashtami Tithi would celebrate on 23rd Aug while who give preference to Rohini Nakshatra would celebrate on 24th Aug.

---

Related

[Why have we celebrated Dussehra today instead of tomorrow?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29551/why-have-we-celebrated-dussehra-today-instead-of-tomorrow/29560#29560)