# Why is Janmashtami always celebrated in the evening?

Tags: krishna, festivals, panchang, celebrations

I read the post about why Janmashtami is celebrated on two different days. But why evening? Like people who give preference to ashtami thithi do it on 23rd Aug 2019 evening, while people who give importance to rohini nakshatra do it on 24th Aug evening

But according to the pamchang, ashtami and rohini is converging in the early hours of 24th morning. So is it okay to do the pooja early in the morning at 4am?

Or is there a stipulation as to why Janmashtami celebration should be done only in the evening.

Comment: Please follow your acharya blind fold.. if you go indepth in understanding than everything will be right from their prespective

Comment: Thank you @Prasanna. But it is just for understanding that I am asking.  Please do let me know if there is a reason to celebrate Janmashtami particularly in the evenings.

Comment: nishitha kala pooja (mid night) should be done when astami thiti and rohini nakshatra was there this is called as Jayanthi Yoga(astrology) this happens only once in a year.. Jayanthi word applies only to krishna now every other birthday is called jayanthi its the Yoga name.. Nishitha kala pooja is given preference in Guruvayur and Udupi based Sriman Madvacharya Jayanthi Kalpa Grantha..

Comment: the festival has to be celebrated in the same kala when the event happened like Dashahra in Vijya kala, Janmashtami in Nishitha kala...

Comment: @Prasanna R thank you.

Comment: @Hemambujavalli, because Krishna was born at midnight. Rama Navami celebrated at noon. Nsimha jayanti celebrated at sunset.

Comment: "Please follow your acharya blind fold" yes if he says to do something really stupid go right ahead. :(.

Comment: @Wikash_, clearly you must be more brilliant than acharyas to figure out what's stupid and what's not

Comment: @ram most people have common sens: it is a good idea to use it instead of following something blindly.

Comment: @Wikash_, exactly. i totally agree with you. don't follow something (like your common sense) blindly. it is a good idea to use the advice of experts instead

Comment: @ram that is not what I said. Isaid to use common sense always. Don't blindly follow someone.

Comment: @Wikash_, i totally agree with you. 'you' are also 'someone'. so don't blindly follow yourself. that is good advice. glad we're on the same page

Comment: @ram if an acharya tells you to jump off a building would you do it?

Comment: @Wikash_, if your common sense tells you to jump off a building would you do it ?

Comment: @ram no never ofcourse that is common sense but that is the thing following someone blindly might lead to serious injuries!

Comment: @Wikash_, following common sense has lead to a lot more serious injuries in actual life, than the hypothetical scenario of acharya asking someone to jump off building which has never happened.

Comment: @ram I would beg to differ. I see people in my environment giving most of their money to such people and blindly following them. Following someone blindly leads almost always to misery. "which has never happened" I am pretty sure it has.

Comment: @Wikash_, then i'm pretty sure a lot more people listened to their common sense and ended up in way worse scenario than simply listening to acharays. next you will ask, how to tell which acharya to follow - that's what you need common sense for. But once you've used up that little common sense to find a satvik guru, you can safely trust them afterwards.

Comment: @ram you did not answer my question.

Comment: @Wikash_, you did not answer my question.

Comment: @ram which question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve the issue

About Two Krishna Janmashtami Dates
Most of the time, Krishna Janmashtami is listed on two consecutive days. The first one is for Smarta Sampradaya and the other one is for Vaishanava Sampradaya. Vaishanava Sampradaya date is the latter one. A single date for Janmashtami means that both Sampradaya would observe Janmashtami on the same date.
However many people will notice unanimity in North India on choosing the day to celebrate Krishna Janmashtami. The reason behind this unanimity is the institution of ISKCON. The International Society for Krishna Consciousness, commonly known as ISKCON is founded on the principles of Vaishnava traditions and most followers of the ISKCON are the followers of Vaishnavism.
With all due respect, ISKCON is one of the most commercialized and global religious institutions which spend money and resources to promote ISKCON brand and ISKCON culture. In North India, most people observe Janmashtami on the day chosen by ISKCON. Many people who are not the followers of Vaishnavism do not even understand that ISKCON traditions are different and the most appropriate day to observe Janmashtami fasting might not be the same as that of ISKCON.
Smarta followers who understand the difference between Smarta and Vaishnava sectarian do not follow ISKCON date to observe Janmashtami fasting. Unfortunately, ISKCON date to observe Janmashtami is unanimously followed in Braj region and most common people who just follow the buzz observe it on the date followed by the ISKCON.
People who are not the followers of Vaishnavism are followers of Smartism. Hindu religious texts like Dharmasindhu and Nirnaysindhu have well-defined rules to decide Janmashtami day and those rules should be followed to decide Janmashtami day if one is not the follower of Vaishnava Sampradaya. Ekadashi fasting is one of the good examples to understand this difference. Rules to observe Ekadashis' fasting are also different for Smarta and Vaishnava communities. However, there is more awareness about different Ekadashi rules followed by Vaishnava sectarian. Not only Ekadashis, Vaishnava fasting day for Janmashtami and Rama Navami might be one day later than Smarta fasting day.
The followers of Vaishnavism give preference to Ashtami Tithi and Rohini Nakshatra. The followers of Vaishnavism never observe Janmashtami on Saptami Tithi. Janmashtami day according to Vaishnava rules always fall on Ashtami or Navami Tithi on Hindu calendar.
However, rules followed by Smartism to decide Janmashtami day are more complex. The preference is given to Nishita Kaal or Hindu midnight. The preference is given to the day, either Saptami Tithi or Ashtami Tithi, when Ashtami Tithi prevails during Nishita and further rules are added to include Rohini Nakshatra. The final consideration is given to the day which has the most auspicious combination of Ashtami Tithi and Rohini Nakshatra during Nishita time. Janmashtami day according to Smarta rules always fall on Saptami or Ashtami Tithi on Hindu calendar.
This page list Janmashtami according to Smarta Sampradaya as well as ISKCON.

This is Panchang for 23 aug Delhi 
Nakshatra can be different for different time zones.

Panchang for Today
New Delhi, India
Saturday, August 24, 2019
Sunrise: 05:59 AM
Tithi: Ashtami upto 08:32 AM
Nakshatra: Rohini upto 04:17 AM, Aug 25

So ashtmi started on August 23 after sunrise. Some people consider 
Nakshatra started after sunrise and some before sunrise.So celebrating it on 23 or 24.
So days can be different but when going for time since KRISHNA was born in night time it will continue in night. I think 23rd is better but stay with the temple you go.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Please provide source which supports your answer. Adding source is mandatory here.

Comment: https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/lord-krishna/krishna-janmashtami-date-time.html?year=2019

Comment: Appended text from website for two days janamashtmi

Comment: Good answer but you last conclusion is contradicting initial statement it should be Aug 24th always astami thithi should be on sunsrise..

Answer (score 2):

The festivals are associated with some event(s). And the main puuja is done in the same time in which the event happened. For example,

- On Ganesha Chaturthi, main Pujaa is done during Madhyahna Kaala because it is believed that Lord Ganesha was born during Madhyahna Kaala (Hindu midday).
- On Raama Navami, main Pujaa is done during Madhyahna Kaala because it is believed that Lord Raama was born during Madhyahna Kaala (Hindu midday).

Similarly,

On Krishna Janmaashtami, main Pujaa is done during Nishita Kaal because it is believed that **Lord Krishna was born during Nishita Kaala (Hindu midnight)**.

---

Related

[Why is Janmashtami celebrated on 2 dates in some parts of India?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36070/why-is-janmashtami-celebrated-on-2-dates-in-some-parts-of-india/36071#36071)

---

Only if sunrise happens at 6am and sunset happens at 6pm, Hindu midday and midnight fall at 12 noon and 12 night respectively. Else, they vary slightly according to sunrise/sunset.

---

Sources:

[drikpanchang > ganesh-chaturthi](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/ganesh-chaturthi/ganesh-chaturthi-date-time.html)

[drikpanchang > rama-navami](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/rama-navami/rama-navami-date-time.html)

[drikpanchang > krishna-janmashtami](https://www.drikpanchang.com/dashavatara/lord-krishna/krishna-janmashtami-date-time.html)